# What's the correct way to let the static member function call a non-static member std::function in c++?

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I'm using an open62541 library who's functions are almost all static. I have to write some callback functions in the open62541's functions, the callback functions are binding to some non-static function.

so the problem is how do I make the:

static function of class A call a std::function, which is bind to non-static function of class B ？

to make the question simpler I make the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

    namespace C {
    std::function<void(void)>C_foo;
    }
    class B
    {
    public:
        B()
        {
            C::C_foo=std::bind(&B::middleMan,this);
        }
        std::function<void(void)>B_foo;
        void middleMan()
        {
            B_foo();
        }
        static void talkTheJoke()
        {
            C::C_foo();
        }
        
    };
    class A
    {
    public:
        void Knock_knock()
        {
            std::cout<<"who's there?"<<std::endl;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        A m_A;
        B m_B;
        // response "who's there?"
        m_A.Knock_knock();

        m_B.B_foo=std::bind(&A::Knock_knock,m_A);
        
        //response "who's there?" again "
        B::talkTheJoke();
        
        return 0;
    }
```

There are class A and their non-static member function A:: Knock_knock(), I want class B's static member function can callback and also acts the same as A:: Knock_knock().

I put a B_foo there as a callback function which would bind the A:: Knock_knock(). Since the B::talkTheJoke() is static and B_foo is not, it seems that B::talkTheJoke() cannot call the B_foo.

So I put a namespace C as a middle man, the std:: function in C can be called by static function B::talkTheJoke(), it can also be bind to non-static std:: function B:: middleMan() which can call the B_foo.

The story would look like:

B::talkTheJoke() ---->  m_B.B_foo --(std::bind)-->  m_A.Knock_knock()   ( X , not works )

B::talkTheJoke() ---->  C::C_foo()  --(std::bind)-->  m_B.middleman() ----> m_B.B_foo  --(std::bind)-->  m_A.Knock_knock() （ O ,works )

However, this solution is really ugly,

what's the correct way to do so?

Comment: you need an object to call a non-static method, be that in another static method or elsewhere

Comment: Notice that you can also define more complex types like `std::vector` or `std::map` or even your own types as static. This allows for greater flexibility when managing callbacks/`std::function` in this use case. However there is no workaround: If the function is just taken in by address  (decay) you'll need some global storage for dynamic behaviour. The alternative is, that the caller provides you with means to pass state around (often seen in c code).

Comment: Why not make `B_foo` static and just get rid of the whole `C` namespace. It's not clear to me why you need it at all.

Comment: Why is it static in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void Knock_knock() {
        std::cout<<"who's there?"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    static void setA( A *a ) {
        m_A = a;
    }

    static void talkTheJoke() {
        if ( m_A != nullptr )
            m_A->Knock_knock();
    }

private:
    static A *m_A;
};

A* B::m_A = nullptr;

int main()
{
    A m_A;
    m_A.Knock_knock();

    B::setA( &m_A );
    B::talkTheJoke();
    return 0;
}
```